# R: Flagging Sample from Same Specimen w/ Different DOB

Tags: r, duplicates, date, data-cleaning

I have a dataset that has duplicate samples that have a different date of birth.  This obviously should not be the case, so I am trying to come up with a way to flag/mark those particular samples. In the end, the only samples that would have 1's next to them would be duplicated samples that have a different DOB, all duplicates that have same DOB and unique samples would have 0's.  Here is a simplified version of the data.

```
test.df<-data.frame(specimen=c("A","A","B","C","B","D","C","D","E"), 
                    DOB=c(as.Date('2000-05-10'),as.Date('2002-04-13'),as.Date('2001-05-12'),as.Date('2003-06-01'),as.Date('2003-04-21'),as.Date('2000-10-20'),as.Date('2003-06-01'),as.Date('2000-10-20'),as.Date('2001-11-23')))
    specimen    DOB
1    A        2000-05-10
2    A        2002-04-13
3    B        2001-05-12
4    C        2003-06-01 
5    B        2003-04-21 
6    D        2000-10-20
7    C        2003-06-01
8    D        2000-10-20
9    E        2001-11-23
```

And would like something like this as end result.

```
 specimen        DOB       diff.dob
1    A        2000-05-10      1
2    A        2002-04-13      1
3    B        2001-05-12      1
4    C        2003-06-01      0
5    B        2003-04-21      1
6    D        2000-10-20      0
7    C        2003-06-01      0
8    D        2000-10-20      0
9    E        2001-11-23      0
```

Identifying duplicates is obviously the easy part, I am just having trouble adding and extra column of 1's and 0's for if the actual duplicates have a different DOB.  Any help would greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `ave`

```
test.df$diff.dob <-  with(test.df, ave(as.numeric(DOB), specimen,
                              FUN=function(x) length(unique(x))!=1))
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
test.df %>%
          group_by(specimen) %>%
           mutate(diff.dob=(n_distinct(DOB)!=1)+0)
#    specimen        DOB diff.dob
#1        A 2000-05-10        1
#2        A 2002-04-13        1
#3        B 2001-05-12        1
#4        C 2003-06-01        0
#5        B 2003-04-21        1
#6        D 2000-10-20        0
#7        C 2003-06-01        0
#8        D 2000-10-20        0
#9        E 2001-11-23        0
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
  setDT(test.df)[,diff.dob:= (!anyDuplicated(DOB) & .N>1)+0 , specimen][]
```

Or another possible option with `base R`

```
indx1 <- !with(test.df, duplicated(DOB)|duplicated(DOB, fromLast=TRUE))
tbl <- table(test.df$specimen)!=1
(test.df$specimen %in% names(tbl)[tbl] & indx1)+0
#[1] 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: thank you, all worked wonderfully. I was previously unfamiliar with "ave" and although I know a little of dplyr, I had not thought of using for this instance.  Thanks again.

Comment: do you think there is a way using base r, something like test.df[duplicated(test.df$specimen .....,]

Comment: @Brad The `ave` solution from `base R` should be pretty fast.  If you need a `duplicated`, I updated my post.